# How to pass ModelAttrubute parameters using MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test

I have this html spring  form:

```
<form:form action="addVacancy" modelAttribute="myVacancy">
        <form:label path="name">name</form:label>
        <form:input path="name" ></form:input>
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <form:label path="description">description</form:label>
        <form:input path="description" id="nameInput"></form:input>
        <form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <form:label path="date">date</form:label>
        <input type="date" name="date" />
        <form:errors path="date" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form:form>
```

I handle this form by this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/addVacancy")
    public ModelAndView addVacancy(@ModelAttribute("myVacancy") @Valid Vacancy vacancy,BindingResult result, Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("message","validation error");
            return new ModelAndView("vacancyDetailsAdd");
        }
        vacancyService.add(vacancy);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:goToVacancyDetails");
        mv.addObject("idVacancy", vacancy.getId());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "added correctly at "+ new Date());
        return mv;
    }
```

How to make the same request, which is obtained after submitting the form. This must be done by means of MockMvc.

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/addVacancy");
    //what must I  write here?
    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);
}
```

I very confused.

Comment: Please don't create accounts so you can ask your questions twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a browser needs to submit a form, it typically serializes the form `<input>` fields as url-encoded parameters. Therefore, when you want to mock an `HttpServletRequest`, you need to add those same parameters to the request.

```
request.param("name", "some value")
       .param("description", "description value")
       .param("date", "some acceptable representation of date");
```

The `DispatcherServlet` will use these parameters to create a `Vacancy` instance to pass as an argument to your handler method.

Comment: let's say you're right. Then why I write    *<form:form action="addVacancy" modelAttribute="myVacancy">* in my form?

Comment: @gstackoverflow `<form:form>` is a Spring tag lib. With `<form>` it binds the `path` attributes of the nested elements to the specified model attribute. The `action` attribute is specifying which URL the request is meant for. I don't understand where your question is coming from

Comment: By this way **<form:form action="addVacancy" modelAttribute="myVacancy">** it is redundant information. Without this string it can works.

Comment: @gstackoverflow I don't understand what you're trying to say. The html form and the mockmvc request are unrelated.

Comment: what the reason write **modelAttribute="myVacancy"** in html form? if this value will not exist in request   which will send to server side?

Comment: @gstackoverflow `modelAttribute` (or the equivalent `commandName`) is used to simplify binding fields of that object. So when you have `input path="name"`, Spring resolves the property `name` on the specified `modelAttribute`, something like (this won't compile, but just for an idea) `request.getAttribute("myVacancy").getName()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the required `@ModelAttribute` object with the `.flashAttr()` method like so:

```
request.flashAttr("myVacancy", new Vacancy()));
```