# Spring Boot tests - posted content is null with @WithMockUser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test my CommentController with a @WithMockUser test, but it seems like it does not find either the user(since the user id (author_id) is null) or content of the comment. I am not sure if the test is done the right way (I am still a beginner), but what I am trying to achieve is the highest code coverage possible, but my previous test does not cover the search of authenticated user and creation of the comment:

`mockMvc.perform(get("/post/3/comment").with(authentication(authentication)).content("content")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).andExpect(view().name("redirect:/post/{id}/"));`

```
package com.paulthemenace.blog.controllers;
import com.paulthemenace.blog.models.Comment;
import com.paulthemenace.blog.models.User;
import com.paulthemenace.blog.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.paulthemenace.blog.services.CommentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import 
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CommentController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;
@Autowired
private CommentService comSrv;

@RequestMapping(value = "/post/{id}/comment")
public String comment(@PathVariable("id") Long id, 
@ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, Model model) throws 
Exception {

    Authentication auth = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (auth != null) {

        String name = auth.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(name);

        if (comment.getContent() != "") {

            comment.setAuthor(currentUser);
            comSrv.create(comment);

        }

    }

    return "redirect:/post/{id}/";
}

}
```

CommentControllerTest

```
    import com.paulthemenace.blog.controllers.CommentController;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

    import 
    org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;

    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;


    import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;

    @SpringBootTest
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration

    public class CommentControllerTest {


    @Autowired
    private CommentController commentController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(commentController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void controllerIsNotNull() {
    assertThat(commentController).isNotNull();
    }


   @Test
   @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "user")
   public void checkIfContainsAuthenticatedUserAndCreatesComment()       
   throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/post/3/comment")
                .content("comment                 
   content")).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/post/{id}/"));


        }


    }
```

stacktrace

https://pastebin.com/2SSKRjwd

Is the test even correct? I want this project to be made in test-driven development but I am failing miserably.
 I googled for resources regarding testing in Spring Boot but none of them helped me solve this matter..

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430365/how-to-pass-modelattrubute-parameters-using-mockmvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link Barath sent, I managed to fix it and get 100% code coverage on that controller:

```
    @Test
@WithMockUser(username = "sure", password = "sure")
public void checkIfContainsAuthenticatedUserAndCreatesComment() throws Exception {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/post/3/comment");

    Comment com = new Comment();
    String name = auth.getName();

    User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(name);

    com.setAuthor(currentUser);
    com.setContent("ahdsf");

    request.flashAttr("comment", com);


    mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/post/{id}/"));


}
```

What was stupid of me, I didn't notice that it was still reading the users from MYSQL, so i had to insert a 'real' user from the table.
Thanks again!